# How to check in an (Android) async task if the activity it was called from was finished?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, asynchronous

I have an android APP which has some async threads running on an activity.
In these threads an alert dialogue box is called under certain conditions.

However if I leave the activity and the alert dialogue tries to open, the APP will crash as the context is no longer valid for display. (NOTE: I don't want the dialogue box to display anyway when the user has moved on/back to another activity).

Is there a way for me to check if the current activity was the activity that called the async task?

This way I can have an 
`if(sameActivity){
    alert.show();
}else{//do nothing}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

if (**mContext instanceof MyActivity**) {

```
    alert.show();
}else{//do nothing}
```

where `mContext` - your current context, `MyActivity` - your activity that called the async task